# python mysql escape \n (simple syntax error)

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

I would like to export a mysql database into a .csv file using this python command.

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'NullServids.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' FROM accounts WHERE srvid is NULL""")
```

But it is returning the following syntax error.

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\n' FROM accounts WHERE srvid is NULL' at line 1")
```

So I tried not escaping the newline character, which obviously works when I copy and paste it into MySQL.

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'NullServids.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM accounts WHERE srvid is NULL""")
```

But I got this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' FROM accounts WHERE srvid is NULL' at line 2")
```

So my question is, what is the proper way to escape the newline character so that is interpreted correctly in the `cursor.execute()` call? I've Googled this and could not find an answer, much to my embarrassment.

Comment: Should just be '\n'. Have you tried simplifying the query, to make sure it really is a problem with the `LINES TERMINATED BY` section? Eg try moving `FROM..WHERE..` after select, and leave off the `INTO` for now. Then add the INTO, one bit at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting that backslashes escapes in string thus \ means nothing.
If you try to print the string you're using you'll see that the places with the backslashes are empty

try this instead:

```
"""SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'NullServids.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' FROM accounts WHERE srvid is NULL"""
```

Comment: It seems i can escape stuff here in SE aswell :D

Comment: Sorry you're not forgetting that at all I see on my second read, but have you tried escaping the first two backslashes?

Comment: Actually, I was forgetting that. So I marked your answer as correct.